# ImmutableJS/FlowType: Is it possible to typeCheck an array returned by a List.toJS()

Tags: javascript, flowtype, immutable.js

Let's say I have this immutable list:

```
type Friend = {
  name: string,
  phone: string
}

const aList: List<Friend> = List([...])
```

Now I have a function with the signature below, that should consume the friend's list:

```
const doStuffs = (friends: Array<Friend>): any => {...}
```

I would like to call it with aList converted to array like this:

```
doStuffs(aList.toJS())
```

But I have a flow error, `aList.toJS()` is not an `Array<Friend>`

Is it possible to typeCheck the result of `aList.toJS()` or do I have to define my function like this:

```
const doStuffs = (friends: Array<any>): any => {...}
```

Comment: Maybe use `toArray()` instead if you are sure your data is compatible?

Comment: Same thing, incompatible with the expected param type.

Comment: I am using toJS() because in fact, my real listItem contains a Record, so I need a deep convertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the `.toJS()` method is returning an array of `Friend`, use a [typecast through any](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/#toc-type-casting-through-any) to let flow know.

E.g.

```
const arrOfFriends = ((aList.toJS(): any): Array<Friend>)
```

I know it sometimes sucks to use `any`, but it's useful if you're *sure* about what's coming out and you don't want to write your own variant of `.toJS()`

Alternatively, you *could* write a method that actually converts the `List<Friend>` to an `Array<Friend>`. Maybe if you want to be *really* sure about the correctness of your code. Personally, I would just go for the `any` typecast as above and write a couple of unit tests.